# Finding subsequences from list

Tags: prolog

Hello i can't figure out how to solve an assignment. I am supposed to find the consecutive element combinations from a list. For example: the list [1,2,3]
should give me [1],[2],[3], [1,2], [2,3], [1,2,3] but the problem i have is that my attempt also gives me [1,3]

Code:

```
subseq([], []).
subseq([H|T], [H|R]) :- subseq(T, R).
subseq([_|T], R) :- subseq(T, R).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that on *each* element of the given list, you have two clauses:

1. the second line where you select the item; and
2. the third line where you do *not* select the item.

So that means you generate all lists where for every item it is an option to include it, or exclude it.

For a subsequence, the ones defined in your question, it is a different story: you basically have *two* selection points:

1. the point where you "start" the subsequence; and
2. the point where you "stop" the subsequence.

Stopping a subsequence is actually the same as generating a *prefix*:

```
myprefix(_, []).
myprefix([H|T], [H|T2]) :-
    myprefix(T, T2).
```

So now for a subsequence, we only need to branch over the *starting point*, and then add a prefix of the remaining list, like:

```
subsequence([H|T], [H|T2]) :-
    myprefix(T, T2).
subsequence([_|T], T2) :-
    subsequence(T, T2).
```

This then yields the expected:

```
?- subsequence([1, 2, 3], X).
X = [1] ;
X = [1, 2] ;
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
X = [2] ;
X = [2, 3] ;
X = [3] ;
false.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I noticed that this solution doesn't work for my schools built in prolog, but it did work on my personal machine!

Comment: @MaxTruedsson this is a fairly simple, generic solution. What exactly failed in your school's Prolog? Maybe `prefix/2` or `subsequence/2` are pre-defined by that system?